# Android how to send data to a running fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

is there a way to send some data from an activity to a **running** fragment?
In my app I'm adding a second fragment over another fragment. I intentionally use the add method instead of the replace method. So now I want to hide my second fragment with

```
fragmentManager.popBackStack();
```

and my first fragment reappears. After hiding the second fragment I want to send some data from my activity to the still running frist fragment.

Any idea how to do this? It doesn't work with bundles (put extra), because I don't rebuild the fragment, I just hide the second one!

Comment: I like using EventBus. https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus

Comment: Use the onResume method to fetch the updates you need from your activity. To see how to comunicate between fragment and activity check [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html) or use EventBus as @SteveM sugested, it is a powerfull lib.

Comment: @Mikel you should make that an actual answer instead of a comment :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one simple solution is:

```
MyFragment oldFragment = (MyFragment) fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_place);

fragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate();

MyFragment newFragment = (MyFragment)fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_place);
newFragment.postData(...);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an EventBus library like [this](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) one, it's easy to use and very convenient.

Comment: An alternative event bus (with pub/sub) would be Otto http://square.github.io/otto/

Answer (score 0):

You can use tags on the Fragments when you create them to call them when needed.

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.content, new SomeFragment(), SomeFragment.class.getSimpleName())
                .commit();
```

So above I use the simple name of the class to tag the fragment when I create and add it to the activity.

```
SomeFragment fragment = (SomeFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(SomeFragment.class.getSimpleName());
```

And I can call it back when I need it and know it is being displayed like above, now I can call send it data like normal by calling a public method in the custom fragment and passing it the data as a param.